# java convert letter to number then put all values into array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out the way to convert letter into number and split it according to n-digits.

For example, I have words: TOMORROW BEGIN

Then, I convert it to number like in ASCII. So, the converting number must be: `8479777982827987326669717378`

After that, all number will be converted to n-digits and put it in one dimensional array.

Let's say the number split to 3 digits each block. Result must be: `847 977 798 282 798 732 666 971 737 8`

They're all in array: `arr[0] = 847, arr[1] = 977, arr[2] = 798,....arr[n]`

I already tried to solve it in java. But so far, I can just converting the string to number.

Here is part of code I've tried:

```
    String words = "TOMORROW BEGIN"; 
    int sa;
    char c; 
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++){ 
      c = words.charAt(i); 
      sa = (int) c;
      String kt = Integer.toString(sa);
      System.out.print(kt);  
    }
```

Well, it successfully converted to number: `8479777982827987326669717378`

But, I confuse how to split the number into blocks of n-digits (let's say 3 digits per block) then put the value of all blocks into array.

What must I do to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create such method:

```
public static int[] splitString(String str, int length){

    int size=str.length()/length;
    if( str.length() % length != 0)
       size++;

    int[] arr = new int[size];
    int a=0;
    for (int i= 0; i < str.length(); i+=length) {
        if(i+length < str.length())
            arr[a++]=Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i, i+length));
        else  
            arr[a++]=Integer.parseInt(str.substring(i,  str.length()));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

At your main method you can just call:

```
String str = "8479777982827987326669717378";
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitString(str,3)));
```

Output:

```
[847, 977, 798, 282, 798, 732, 666, 971, 737, 8]
```

You can even specify to store 2 digit `int` into array

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitString(str, 2)));
```

Output:

```
[84, 79, 77, 79, 82, 82, 79, 87, 32, 66, 69, 71, 73, 78]
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to take `substring` on every three characters and convert each substring back using `Integer.parseInt()`.

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "8479777982827987326669717378";
    int n = 3;
    int[] output = new int[(input.length() + n - 1) / n];
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        output[i] = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(i*n, Math.min((i+1)*n, input.length())));
       // System.out.println(output[i]);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use substring method for splitting a string

eg:

```
  for (int start = 0; start < kt.length(); start += size) {

           system.out.println(kt.substring(start, Math.min(kt.length(), start + size)))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try it this way:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String words = "TOMORROW BEGIN";
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int idx = 0; idx < words.length(); idx++) {
      builder.append((int) words.charAt(idx));
    }
    int[] ints = new int[(builder.length() + 2) / 3];
    for (int idx = 0; idx < ints.length; idx++) {
        int from = idx * 3;
        int to = Math.min(from + 3, builder.length());
        ints[idx] = Integer.parseInt(builder.substring(from, to));
    }
    System.out.println(builder);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
8479777982827987326669717378
[847, 977, 798, 282, 798, 732, 666, 971, 737, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate ASCII to a String or a StringBuffer, then loop through it.

Based on your code:

```
String words = "TOMORROW BEGIN"; 
int sa;
char c; 

StringBuffer asciiBuffer = new StringBuffer();
for(int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++){ 
    c = words.charAt(i); 
    sa = (int) c;
    asciiBuffer.append(Integer.toString(sa));
}
    
System.out.println("\nBuffer: " + asciiBuffer);

int from = 0;
int arrayStringLength = 3;
int bufferLength = asciiBuffer.length();
int arraySize = bufferLength / arrayStringLength + 1;
CharSequence[] result = new CharSequence[arraySize];
int i=0;

while(from < bufferLength){
    result[i] = asciiBuffer.subSequence(from, Math.min(from+arrayStringLength, bufferLength));
    from = from+arrayStringLength;
    i++;
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
```

Output:

> Buffer: 8479777982827987326669717378
>
> [847, 977, 798, 282, 798, 732, 666, 971, 737, 8]

See [this ideone](https://ideone.com/RaLEYl).

*EDIT:* Compared to other answer storing result in an integer array, 0 will be conserved in a CharSequence array. Example of potential issue with integer solutions, with "TPMORROW BFGIN" as entry:

> Buffer: 8480777982827987326670717378
>
> [848, 077, 798, 282, 798, 732, 667, 071, 737, 8]

Answer (score 1):

I used your code and added a few lines. This should work :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

      String words = "TOMORROW BEGIN"; 
        int sa;
        int n = 3; // put any value for n
        char c; 
        int[] array;
        String kt = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length(); i++){ 
          c = words.charAt(i); 
          sa = (int) c;
          kt += sa;
        }
        System.out.println(kt);
        int nbPartitions = kt.length() / n + kt.length() % n;
        array = new int[nbPartitions];

        for(int i = 0; i < nbPartitions; i++){
            int begin = i * n;
            int end = (i + 1) * n;
            if(end > kt.length()){
                array[i] = Integer.parseInt(kt.substring(begin, kt.length()));
                break;
            }
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(kt.substring(begin, end));
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}
```